# R create a svg with ggplot 2 and customize it

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I create a graph with *ggplot2* and then write a *.svg* of it with the *gridSVG* package.

I also want to arbitrarily modify the resulting *.svg* by adding attributes to it. However, I haven't found a good way to do so. Currently I use the 'gridSVG::grid.garnish' function in the following fashion

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridSVG)

x <- rnorm(1000)
breaks <- c(-1.75, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.75)
g <- ggplot(as.data.frame(x),  aes(x = x)) +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = breaks, aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill='green', alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks) +
  ylab("Density") + xlab("Measure") + ggtitle("Histogram") + theme_bw()

plot(g)

gridSVG::grid.export('histogram.svg', strict = FALSE)
breakLabels <- c('verylow', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'veryhigh')
lss <- grid::grid.ls()
tag <- lss$name[match('axis.2-1-2-1', lss$name) + 1L]
gridSVG::grid.garnish(tag, breaklabels = breakLabels, group = FALSE)
gridSVG::grid.export('histogram.svg', strict = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

This gets the job done but it isn't good code since the graph is written twice and the script may not be portable to be executed in another computer.

So my question is, how can I write an *.svg* with *ggplot2* **while** having a simple way to modify the resulting file?

An example where the breaks of the previous histogram gain a new attribute would be great.

Comment: [svglite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svglite/svglite.pdf) device allows to access to XML tree of created document (`xmlSVG`). But I don't tested it with ggplot2.

Comment: `svglite` does a great job with ggplot2 plots.

Comment: svglite no longer works.